# Listing nouns (using "and")

Tags: translation, particles

I'm practicing particles as well as general grammar and I'm wondering if this is an accurate translation of the English statement: "I like sunshine, candy, and apples."

> 私は日光やキャンディやりんごが好きです。

I have two questions beyond "Is this right?":

- Do I need to put commas in between the nouns even though they're separated by the particle (や)?
- In the original English statement, I used the conjunction "and" (そして), is this needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't put commas after the nouns because that is not how commas are used in Japanese. At least not when you're using the particles to denote a listing, but that is a completely different story altogether.

The way you have it written is perfectly fine. One thing to note is that や implies a partial listing, while と a complete listing.

As for そして, that one is used to express a sequence of loosely connected events. I barely use it in spoken Japanese, because I feel it's too stiff. Unless you wanted to stress the fact that something happened after another action, you're better off using the て form of verbs to link sentences.

Instead of this, for example:

> [仕事帰り]{しごとがえり}にコンビニに[寄る]｛よる｝。**そして**[晩ご飯]｛ばんごはん｝を[買う]｛かう｝。
> I'll stop by the convenience store on the way from work and buy dinner.

you'd be better off saying this:

> [仕事帰り]{しごとがえり}にコンビニに[寄]｛よ｝**って**[晩ご飯]｛ばんごはん｝を[買う]｛かう｝。